# Upload image in wordpress media

Tags: wordpress

How upload image use `<input type="file">` in front end form in wordpress?

in this moment i have this code:

```
<form method="post">

<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="file" />
<input type="submit" />

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In functions.php

```
<?php
function insert_attachment($file_handler,$post_id,$setthumb='false') {

  // check to make sure its a successful upload
  if ($_FILES[$file_handler]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) __return_false();

  require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
  require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
  require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

  $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file_handler, $post_id );

  if ($setthumb) update_post_meta($post_id,'_thumbnail_id',$attach_id);
  return $attach_id;
}
?>
```

In your theme file:

```
<?php
if ($_FILES) {

foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
    $newupload = insert_attachment($file,$pid);
}
};
?>
```

Comment: i try this code but not upload file in upload directory

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have a more updated code about how to use the media_handle_upload() function as at the wordpress site : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_handle_upload

It uses the `<input type="file">` in its upload form.